# How lucene deals with deleted document from inverted index?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, inverted-index

I wonder what's the way Lucene to deal with deleted documents.

I know about segments and how lucene mark a document is deleted

Since in the inverted index, each word would be mapped with numerous of document id

for example:

```
harry: 1,2,3
potter: 9,10,1
half: 1,6,3
```

to remove document id = 1, lucene have to walk through all those word to strip document id = 1?
iterating over them to remove is extreme costly.

Answer (score 1):

Lucene has a concept of `segments` that are immutable , hence when a document is deleted its not deleted from the original segment where its originally created, when its deleted its marked as deleted in the new segment and when Elasticsearch searches documents it searches in all the segements and when it sees the entry in both old and new segment it sees that its deleted in the new segment, so it removes the deleted document from the search result.

And merge segment finally merges old segments and in that process removes the deleted documents and creates a new segment.

Refer [merge process](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-merge.html) for more info.

Comment: This is also very helpful to understand the concept of segment merging: https://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/02/visualizing-lucenes-segment-merges.html

Comment: I know about segments, but like i said, looping through inverted index in each segment to find deleted document is costly, im not sure it would do it in the merging process. It kinda like rebuild entire segment to strip all deleted docs and would cause the performance

Comment: This is how it works, i.e. from the [Lucene docs](https://lucene.apache.org/core/9_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene92/package-summary.html#package.description): When documents are deleted, gaps are created in the numbering. These are eventually removed as the index evolves through merging. **Deleted documents are dropped when segments are merged**. A freshly-merged segment thus has no gaps in its numbering.

Comment: @TomSawyer let me know if you have any further question

Comment: @TomSawyer do you have any followup question?

Comment: @Amit-ESenthusiast Yes, the question is persited. i'm looking for the code how elastic re-index the inverted index to strip all deleted docs, since like i said, it would cause performance issue to reindex again. The question is how it works efficently

Comment: @TomSawyer got it, i think its better to ask this on https://discuss.elastic.co/ where elastic team members can help you with code and deeper insights about it, although its not Elasticsearch related, its related to Lucene that Elasticsearch uses

Comment: @TomSawyer did you get update from elastic folks?